# How to plot combine two heatmaps on top of each other in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, heatmap, superimpose

I have two heatmaps I've made in python. I use `seaborn` for both of them, but I'm not wedded to it.

Both these heatmaps are on the same 20x20 grid. One of the heatmaps is a background, dividing the 20x20 grid into 3 large regions. The other heatmap shows a hotspot, a smaller box that is lit up, and then the rest of the background is zero.

I would like to superimpose the heatmap with the hotspot in front of the background heatmap. I haven't found anything remotely helpful. Does anyone know of a good way to do this? I haven't found how to do this in seaborn.

Here is my sample code, where `background` is one of the arrays and `hotspot` is the other array.

```
sns.heatmap(background)
sns.heatmap(hotspot, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.show()
```

But this just shows the heatmap for `hotspot.` I would like the heatmap for `hotspot` superimposed on the background.

Answer (score 1):

`heatmap` is an Axes-level function and therefore you can just give it an axes as an argument.

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(background, ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(hotspot, cmap='RdBu_r', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You probably need to convert the zeros of `hotspot` to `NaN`s to prevent erasing the background.